# WinRT cumstom slider style

Tags: windows-runtime, slider, winrt-xaml

I want to style a slider for my Win 8.1 App. For that I've created a new style with the TargetType "Slider".

```xml
<Style x:Key="SliderThumbStyle" TargetType="Thumb">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ThumbBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ThumbBorderThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                <Grid>
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="Slider">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Slider">
                <Grid>
                    <Border Height="45"
                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Background="Transparent" />
                    <Grid x:Name="MainDisplay" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="13" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="13" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Ellipse Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Height="13" Width="13" Stroke="#7B838A" StrokeThickness="3"/>
                        <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" 
                                   Grid.Column="1" 
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                   Stretch="Fill" 
                                   Fill="#7B838A" 
                                   Height="3"/>
                        <Ellipse Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Height="13" Width="13" Stroke="#7B838A" StrokeThickness="3"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Canvas>
                        <Thumb x:Name="PART_Thumb"
                               Background="#D7DEE5"
                               Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyle}"
                               Width="160"
                               Height="45"
                               Opacity="0.5"
                               Canvas.ZIndex="-1"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Canvas>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

On my page I use the slider like this:

```xml
<Slider VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
```

So far so good the slider looks like I wanted.
But the slider is frozen and the "Thumb" stays on the left side and I can't move it.
Why does this happen? What do I need to change that I can move the slider?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's because the Slider expects certain elements to exist so the code can reference them. Within your inner Grid there needs to be two Rectangle elements and a Thumb as a bare minimum.  This enables the code to move the Thumb by re-sizing the Rectangles. The element names have to be specific for this to work.

If you look inside generic.xaml and search for TargetType="Slider", you can examine the default style and find the exact names.

I've modified your Style so the Thumb can now be moved. I'm not sure if it still meets your requirements in terms of appearance, but you should be able to modify it from here.

```
<Style TargetType="Slider">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Slider">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Ellipse Grid.Column="0" Height="13" Width="13" Stroke="#7B838A" StrokeThickness="3" />

                        <Grid Name="HorizontalTemplate" Grid.Column="1">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Rectangle Name="HorizontalTrackRect"
                                       Grid.Column="0" 
                                       Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                       Stretch="Fill" 
                                       Fill="#7B838A" 
                                       Height="3" />

                            <Thumb Name="HorizontalThumb"
                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                   Background="#D7DEE5"
                                   Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyle}"
                                   Width="160"
                                   Height="45"
                                   Opacity="0.5" />

                            <Rectangle Name="HorizontalDecreaseRect"
                                       Grid.Column="0"
                                       Fill="Red"
                                       Height="3" />

                        </Grid>
                        <Ellipse Grid.Column="2" Height="13" Width="13" Stroke="#7B838A" StrokeThickness="3" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```